# Strange black bar filling when using geom_bar and facet_wrap to plot the number of RNA-editing-events at each genomic coord, split by chr, 4 genotypes

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have an ordered dataframe:

```
edit_metric.mean <- edit_metric.mean[with(edit_metric.mean, order(chr, start, -edit_metric)), ]
head(edit_metric.mean)
        chr   start   geno edit_metric
1006983   1 3263157 ADAR_O           1
1006984   1 3263159 ADAR_O           1
1006985   1 3263161 ADAR_O           1
1006986   1 3263163 ADAR_O           1
1006987   1 3263165 ADAR_O           1
1006988   1 3263167 ADAR_O           1
```

The data contains four experimental genotypes. The data is sorted by chromosome, start position, and descending edit_metric. I plot the data with:

```
ggplot(edit_metric.mean,aes(x=start,y=edit_metric,color=geno)) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_identity(), stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~chr,scales="free") + 
  theme(aspect.ratio=1, axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank()) +
  ylab("Edit-Events * Edit-Rate") +
  ggtitle(label="Average Edit-Events*Edit-Rate per Edit-Site, by Genotype")
```

[image: RNA editing coverage, by chromosome, grouped by genotype]

For small unplaced scaffold chromosomes, GL456221.1, GL456233.2, and GL456385.1, a strange black bar appears filling the bars. Why is this happening. How can I keep this from happening?

After consulting with AI, it was suggested that I add hard x and y axis limits, but this did not remove the mysterious black bars. I also want to remove the black boxes filling the legend keys.

Comment: Try with mapping on `fill` instead of `color`, i.e. use `fill = geno`. With `color` you only set the color for the outline of the bars, while you get a black fill by default.

Comment: @stefan
This altered the behavior considerably, plotting only the panels where the black bars previously appeared, leaving all other panels empty. I believe normal chromosomes are so large that the fill area in the bars is not visible, thereby leaving blank plots for these panels. I added fill=geno to aes, but kept color=geno, and this solved the problem. Thank you for reminding me that black was the default fill!

Comment: If those only have limited data, with `scales = "free"`, it makes the lines thicker and look like bars.

Comment: Remove the `"free"` and see if it solves the problem.  Perhaps specifying the x axis explicitly, e.g. `scale_x_continuous()` will also work